# Object merge function from Definitive Guide to JavaScript acting exactly like extend function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, utility

I'm at the Objects chapter in the Definitive Guide to JavaScript and I'm messing around with some object utility functions that Flanagan shares.

The two in question are the extend() and merge() functions:

```
/* Copy enumerable props of p to o, and return o. */
/* Same name props, o is overwritten */

function extend(o, p) {
  for (prop in p) {
    o[prop] = p[prop];
  }
  return o;
}

/* Copy the enumerable props of p to o, and return o.
/* Same name props, o's property is left alone. */

function merge(o, p) {
  for(prop in p) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty[prop]) continue;
    o[prop] = p[prop];
  }
  return o;
}
```

To see the effect of the different functions, I tried:

```
var x = {
  a: 1,
};
var y = {
  a: 4,
  b: 5,
  c: 6
};

merge(x, y);
```

Which returns x as *Object { a=4, b=5, c=6}* I thought that x's matching properties should not have been overwritten. I also tried

```
extend(x, y);
```

Which returns x as *Object { a=4, b=5, c=6}*

Does anyone have any insight as to why these functions are behaving identically? I've looked around Stack Overflow for a while but can't find anything addressing this behavior specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `merge`, should be `o.hasOwnProperty(prop)` (parens instead of brackets):

```
function merge(o, p) {
  for(prop in p) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
    o[prop] = p[prop];
  }
  return o;
}
```

Comment: I was just playing with that and could not see it - nice find :)

Comment: @go-oleg Thank you very much, that fixed it! I guess I get points for attention to detail but not critical thinking - that was how it was written in the book